# App Engine Development Server Does Not Reload Code When Changed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk, devserver

I'm working on a python app that will run on top of Google App Engine. I setup my app up with the following directory structure:

```
approot/
  app.yaml
  index.yaml
  myapp.py
  controllers/
   some_controller.py
   some_controller1.py
  models/
  views/

...etc...
```

My problem is that the development server will not always automatically reload my code when I make changes even though Google's documentation says it will.

The only time it does reload my code is when the change I make is in the top level directory of my app. Anything in a subdirectory (e.g. controllers) is ignored. I have to stop and start the server every time a change is made.

I find this really impedes my progress in development, especially since there is no restart button, you actually have to hit stop and then start.

Is there a remedy for this or am I just doing it wrong? I really like having a well organized project and would rather not dump all my files in the top level directory.

Comment: Please file a bug report at: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: I'm hesitant to file a bug as I don't know if I'm doing something incorrectly or if this is an actual bug. Heck it may even be a feature request for all I know :)

Comment: If it's not doing what you want it to do, it's a short coming.  If nobody has reported something similar, then it's not a duplicate.  Even if the project owners disagree with your opinion of how it should work, that should be documented.  File a bug report!

Comment: OK, bug filed: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4830

Comment: @macinhosh I am using pydev plugin in eclipse and i don't have any problem in seeing the changes without restarting the server even in the sub directory. Which os you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reload mechanism is likely tied to the default import mechanism and builtin `__import__` function.  If you (or your framework) load your modules in some other, clever way, the reloader might not notice.  A possible workaround is to explicitly import key modules in your `myapp.py` module.

Comment: I'm using from ... import ... would that fall under the default import mechanism? I'm still pretty new to Python so pardon my ignorance :)

Comment: Are the modules that you are changing being imported in that way, in `myapp.py`?

Comment: Yes in myapp.py I have something like: "from SomeController import SomeController" SomeController is a class declared in controllers/SomeController.py with the path being relative to myapp.py

Comment: If you're interested you can download some sample code that replicates this issue from my bug report: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4830

Answer (score 0):

double check that you have installed pyobjc

the dev server will complain like this:

UserWarning: Detecting source code changes is not supported because your Python version   does not include PyObjC (http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/). Please install PyObjC or, if that is  not practical, file a bug at http://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/issues/list.